# How to use tab character for indentation in PhpStorm?

Tags: indentation, phpstorm

The setting for the switch from space characters to tabs is `Use tab character` ([`Settings... -> Editor -> Code Style (-> {LANGUAGE}) -> [checkbox] Use tab character`](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-style-php.html#d589320e255)). But it works for me only in new files.

I've just created a new Zend Framework 2 skeleton based project. When I create a new file and edit it, tabs are used. But it doesn't work in the files, that already were there on project creating (e.g. `/public/index.php`, `/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml`, `/public/css/style.css`).

Is it a bug? How to make PhpStorm use tabs in all files?

Answer (score 7):

Updated for PhpStorm 2016.3:

Preferences > Editor > Code Style

Uncheck "Indents Detection > Detect and use existing file indents for editing"

Answer (score 5):

Go to **Preferences => Code Style** then scroll to the bottom and uncheck the **Enable EditorConfig support** option. This was overriding my 4 space tab setting.

Comment: Unchecking this option also works for WebStorm. I had a similar problem with my React .jsx templates not applying tabs.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots? I did not find " Enable EditorConfig support".

Comment: @JulianMoreno These are the updated steps for the 2017.3.5 version. You need to now go to **Preferences** (mac) or **File** (win) and select **Settings => Editor => Code Style** and then uncheck **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** under the **Indents Detection** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat those files: in the main menu select **"Code -> Reformat Code"**. That will switch space characters to tabs, if the setting is set to "Use tab character". You can also do it on folders, it will reformat all files inside.

Comment: For me, "Code > Reformat Code" is creating a mixture of tabs and spaces. Every time I hit Enter, it indents with tabs (as expected), then adds two space characters. Very aggravating. I installed the EditorConfig plugin and created a .editorconfig file, but no difference.

Comment: Resolved the issue by adding `indent_size = 4` to my .editorconfig file. The bug seems to be triggered when tabs are used for indentation and an indent size isn't set.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I don't want to reformat the whole file? Kind of makes a mess of Version Tracking when I just want my new work to use tabs!

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty because my tab size was set larger than my indent size. When I set both equal (4 in my case), PhpStorm started behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows and Linux**

File | Settings | Editor | Code Style |  | Tabs and Indents

**For macOS**

PhpStorm | Preferences | Editor | Code Style |  | Tabs and Indents

﻿